# what is the best way to save pixmap content to widget

Tags: c++, qt

I am using such code:

```
void MyWidget::paintEvent(QPaintEvent *event)
{
  QPixmap temp(width(), height());
  QPainter painter(&temp);
  // drawing code ...
  painter.end();
  QPainter painter2(this);
  painter2.drawPixmap(0, 0, width(), height(), temp);
}
```

but i am not sure that it is the best way to use pixmap

Comment: What does `save pixmap` mean?

Comment: I want to copy pixmap's image  to widget

Comment: Don't you mean that you want to *draw* the pixmap in the widget?

Comment: Yes. My code shows this idea.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the only way to draw pixmap on QWidget, as I know, but better and more comfortable to draw items on QGraphicScene. Also, you can draw it on QWidget directly, if there is no need in pixmap.

Answer (score 1):

The best way to display a pixmap is to use `QLabel`. You can use `QLabel::setPixmap` to display a pixmap and don't need to reimplement any functions. You can create pixmap once and put it on the label, and this is more efficient than creating pixmap in each paint event.

Also `QGraphicScene` is indeed more convenient for drawing.